# jbuttons only showing after i hover over them

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

i am making a game in java and i want to have buttons that will run the game and close the game. both buttons work but they only show up after i hover over them.

```
public class Menu extends JPanel  {
static boolean load = false;
JButton play = new JButton("play");
JButton close= new JButton("close");
boolean g = false;

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g); 
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    draw(g2d);
    add(play);
    add(close);
}
public Menu(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    setVisible(true);  
    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            g = true;
            GamePanel.store1.clear();
            if(g){
                GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(560,680));
                add(panel,0,0);
                panel.setFocusable(true);
                panel.requestFocusInWindow();
                validate();  
            }
        }
     });
    close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
     });



}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){

    g2d.drawImage(getBulletImage(),0,0,null);

}



// gets the image file for the player class
public Image getBulletImage(){
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("Menu.png");
    return ic.getImage();
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Why are you calling add() from paint()? That seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the problems I see.

1. Read your image once in the constructor, then draw it as many times as you wish.
2. Don't override the JPanel paint method.  Override the JPanel paintComponent method.
3. I don't see your JFrame instantiation at all, but be sure to instantiate your JFrame with the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.

I'm not sure these tips will fix your problem, since you did not provide runnable code for any of us to test.

Answer (score 0):

Move both your add() method calls from paint() into the constuctor

Comment: i did that and nothing changed. any other ideas?

Comment: try overriding paintComponent() or paintComponents() instead of paint(). And leave the add() methods inside the constructor.